# How to uninstall influxdb with all its data and configuration files

Tags: centos7, influxdb

I am storing the data in the influx to create a dashboard with grafana.

But my influx database is getting crashed after 1 day due to large amount of data ingestion in influx.

No my centos file system(memory) got full. I am not able to restart the influx also.

I want to delete all the data that has been stored by influx to free up the space in centos.

I have deleted the below directories:

```
/var/lib/influxdb/data
/var/lib/influxdb/wal
/var/lib/influxdb/meta
```

Didn't find any proper documentation on internet to uninstall influx db.

Can anyone provide the details to uninstall influx db with all its data.

Comment: How did you install it in the first place? If you installed it  from a package (i.e., using `yum install`), then you can remove it the same way (`yum remove`). If you installed it from source, then removing it is entirely up to you. In either case, removing the data will probably be a manual step.

Comment: I have installed it using the sudo rpm -ivh influxdb-0.9.4_rc1-1.x86_64.rpm command

Comment: So you can remove it with `yum remove influxdb`, or `rpm -e influxdb`, although you should in general not be using `rpm` by itself to install/remove packages (it won't hurt in this case). You will still probably need to remove any data yourself, although by removing `/var/lib/influxdb` you've probably taken care of that already.

Comment: Thanks i was able to uninstall using your command.

Comment: I did install using 'sudo dpkg -i influxdb_1.7.9_amd64.deb' , wondering how to completely uninstall or remove it?

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove influxdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in order:

```
pkill -f influx   [To kill any running influx Process]
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove influxdb  [Remove all the files, data files generally stays]
go to /var/lib/influxdb/data directory and issue command rm -rf * command.
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove influxDB v2:
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove influxdb2

Comment: Please explain the efffect of the difference to the exidting, older and upvoted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66995131/7733418 and which advantages it offers. Try to make more obvious what additional insight your answer contributes. And maybe generally try for [answer].