# How to uninstall influxdB in windows

Tags: windows, influxdb, influxdb-2

I initially thought that i would require influxdB but stands out I actually don't need it and now I want to uninstall it. Please suggest how to do it cleanly.
The other post I saw is for centos. [How to uninstall influxdb with all its data and configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833787/how-to-uninstall-influxdb-with-all-its-data-and-configuration-files)

even their website does not have any documentations.
No documentation available?
Will deleting the folder solve my problem?